# Does it hold that if we have a subset B closed in X, and C closed in B, that C is closed in X?

Tags: general-topology

I’m convinced that if we replace closed with open in the above statement, this does not hold. I’m picturing a closed segment on $\mathbb R$, which I believe would also be closed on $\mathbb R^2$. I can’t think of any violating examples.

But this is hardly a proof. An attempt at a proof might follow: given a closed subset $C\subset B$, $B’$ is open in $C$, and if we extend $C$ to some larger set $X$ (like $\mathbb R^2$), we can construct open sets not containing $C$ on $X$ whose union is open on $X$ (I think I’m allowed to say this?)

Struggling through the logic here, help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.If $B$ is closed in $X$ and $C\subset B$ is closed in $B$ then $B$ \ $C$ is open in $B.$ So $B$ \ $C=B\cap U$ for some $U$ which is open in $X.$ So we have

$C=B$ \ $(B$ \ $C)=B$ \ $(B\cap U)=B$ \ $U = B\cap (X$ \ $U).$

Now $X$ \ $U$ is closed in $X$ and $B$ is closed in $X$ so  $B\cap (X$ \ $U)$ is closed in X.

2. If $B$ is open in $X$ and $C\subset B$ is open in $B$ then $C=B\cap U$ for some $U$ which is open in $X$. Now $B$ is open in $X$ and $U$ is open in $X$ so $B\cap U$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Your first and best tool to use is often just a definition. E.g. the 1st & 2nd sentences of 1. and the 1st sentence of 2.

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is closed in $B$ this means there is a closed $C'$ of $X$ ($\Bbb R$ or the plane, whatever the main space is) such that $C' \cap B =C$.

And if $B$ is also closed in $X$ we have just written $C$ as an intersection of closed subsets of $X$ and so $C$ is also closed in $X$.

The same essential proof and fact holds when we use "open" twice instead of closed (because the intersection is finite).